# Jersey REST application not visible from Amazon EC2

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jersey, grizzly

I have a simple REST Jersey application:

```
@Path("/rest")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/test")
    public String test() {
        return "It works!";
    }
}
```

The application is hosted by a Grizzly2 web container:

```
public class Main {

    private static int getPort(int defaultPort) {
        ...
        return defaultPort;
    }

    public static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseURI();

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://0.0.0.0/").port(getPort(9998)).build();
    }

    protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
        final Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

        initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "MyResourceServer");

        System.out.println("Starting grizzly2...");
        return GrizzlyWebContainerFactory.create(BASE_URI, initParams);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Grizzly 2 initialization
        HttpServer httpServer = startServer();
        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...",
                BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        httpServer.stop();
    }    
}
```

I've deployed the jar files to my EC2 Windows Instance and I can access the service from the private IP address or localhost:

```
http://localhost:9998/rest/test
```

in browser returns "It works!". However I cannot access the service with my public address, although I've allowed all TCP inbound traffic in the Security Group of my EC2 instance. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: Can you ping the public address? Is the Windows firewall active?

Comment: Huh I forgot about Windows Firewall... I just had to add a rule for the that as well. Thank you!